# Launch each Windows Explorer window in a separete process

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, process, threads, multi-threaded

Win7 Win64. I configured Windows Explorer in Tools > Folder Options > View > Launch folder windows in a separate process. It is checked, to make sure I rebooted Windows and it was still checked.

Still, if I open a lot of Windows Explorer windows, there are still only 2 explorer.exe running. I even tried to directly execute explorer.exe and it didn't work. I believe that option makes WinExplorer and Desktop run each on its own process.

But I want each window to have its own process, so that if needed I can kill a process without losing other ones. It doesn't need to be everytime, it would be perfect if explorer.exe had a parameter to make it open new process instead of opening a window inside the existing one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `explorer.exe /seperate` switch, although it would always default to your My Documents.

As you can see below, I have run the `explorer.exe /seperate` command twice, and thus have three explorer.exe process.

[image: Seperate Explorer Windows]